# Can a Matlab script node in Labview communicate during execution?

Tags: matlab, labview

In Labview, can a Matlab script node (or a Mathscript node) in a block diagram communicate (that is, read inputs and update outputs) during its execution ?

Put another way, can such a script node communicate with other elements on the block diagram during its execution, without waiting for the script to terminate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible. I've never seen anyone be able to pass information from inside the MathScript node to the outside (a.k.a rest of the block diagram) world while it is executing. You can pass information from one MathScript node to another and from the node to the LabVIEW MathScript Window if you use [globals](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvconcepts/glob_variables/). These globals are different than the LabVIEW global variable though.

Grant Heimbach
LabVIEW Product Manager
grant.heimbach@ni.com

Comment: In this case, it makes sense to call NI VIs from Matlab through ActiveX for this kind of stuff.
(see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299817/how-can-a-labview-vi-be-run-as-a-background-task-through-an-activex-call-with
)

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely and perfectly possible. Wire inputs, create outputs, if data should change potentially during running the script, create multiple scripts instead, introduce breakpoints, or run subscripts in a loop and check data on every iteration, updating selectively.

By the way, the Matlab script node, and the MathScript node are two different things, look it up.

Mr product manager above does not have a clue of what he's talking about.