# How can a Labview VI be run as a background task through an ActiveX call ? (without keeping ActiveX busy)

Tags: matlab, activex, labview

I would like to execute a Labview VI through ActiveX in Matlab.

I use the following commands:

```
e=actxserver('LabVIEW.Application');
vipath='C:\DATA\Labview\test.vi';
vi=invoke(e,'GetVIReference',vipath);
vi.Run;
```

This works correctly and the VI is seen to execute on its front panel.
However, Matlab keeps waiting until the VI has terminated.
I want Labview to run the VI silently, without telling Matlab (through ActiveX) to wait.

How can a VI be executed without keeping ActiveX busy ? Is there a standard way to do so ? (I assume there should be, given how multitask-oriented Labview is - which is not the case of Matlab in its standard form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer (thanks to smercurio_fc on the NI forum):

To run the VI in the background (without waiting until done):
        vi.Run(1);

To run it and wait until its execution is complete:
        vi.Run(0);
or
        vi.Run;

In the background execution mode with *vi.Run(1)*, execution can be interrupted with *vi.Abort*. During execution, input and output values can be changed with vi.SetControlValue and vi.GetControlValue.
For instance, to get the value of a numerical control 'z' during execution:
        vi.GetControlValue('z')

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Launch LabVIEW.exe as a process, specifying VI as argument (search help for this). There is for sure a way to tell Matlab to not wait for end of process execution
- Run the VI dynamically, using VI server, inside a launcher VI, and have Matlab call the launcher VI. The latter will return immediately after calling your VI, and Matlab will not wait for your main VI to end.

Comment: Actually, I would like to do it through the VI server (which is what the code does, I believe).
I was told that I could set the "Wait Until Done" parameter of the "Run" method to False, but unfortunately I didn't manage to access this parameter through Matlab (even though I could do it from inside Labview).
The Run method of the vi object is listed as:
"Run(handle, Variant(Optional))"

Comment: There is a related (although more general) question with more details on this issue on this forum post:  

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Different-ActiveX-methods-appear-when-referencing-a-VI-inside-or/td-p/1879185

Comment: Oh you mean wrapping the VI that I want to call in a caller VI that sets the "Wait Until Done" parameter, and running the caller VI from Matlab ? It's a workaround, but it will definitely solve my problem :) Thanks for the idea !